# How to change website URL in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been searching for a while, but I can't seem to figure out how to change my website url in visual studio 2015. Right now it's going off of `localhost:9045`, but I need to change it to a different port number and a path, `localhost:54865/central`.
Changing the port number is simple enough, as that's just a setting in the Debug tab in the web site project file. But can't seem to find a way to add the extra path at the end...
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using that `URL` box in the bottom?

Comment: It's disabled. It only gets "enabled" when I check `Enable SSL`. However, although it looks enabled, I still can't enter anything in there. Not sure how to use that feature.

Comment: You can publish your solution on IIS.

Comment: I'm using IIS Express though. I used to be able to do this with the old Web Application projects in 2013, all with IIS Express. So I'm thinking there's some configuration somewhere I'm missing.

Comment: Website Projects and Web Application projects are different. If you convert your Website Project back to a Web Application project you'll get the option back. Why are you using a Website project anyway? Web Application projects are by no means deprecated.

Comment: We went with a Web Site because we don't have Razor pages or cshtml pages, we're all straight html/css/js with SPA frameworks. Therefore, the overhead of a web app was too much. It would seem strange though that I would not be able to change the url of my web site, only web application... Perhaps there is a different approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to open the `.vs/config/applicationhost.config`, which is in the same folder as your solution file.

Locate your website in `configuration/configSections/sites` and overwrite the auto-assigned port under `site/bindings/binding/bindingInformation`.

Be sure to save the solution & restart your development server, and you should be good to go on your chosen port.

Comment: Actually ended up solving this a while ago by doing exactly what you mentioned, but forgot that I had asked this question :) Thanks for your response, hopefully it helps somebody else down the line who is trying to figure out the same question.

Comment: Good deal.  Thanks Andrew.