# How to change startup url of old website project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I want to change the startup url/port number for my project in VS 2022. It's an old website project. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Look for `applicationHost.config` in `.vs` in your solution dir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742241/how-to-change-website-url-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open the .vs/config/applicationhost.config, which is in the same folder as your solution file.

Locate your website in configuration/configSections/sites and overwrite the auto-assigned port under site/bindings/binding/bindingInformation.

Be sure to save the solution & restart your development server, and you should be good to go on your chosen port.

Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39481294/20528460